# c++ overload operators

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm noobie in c++.
I have class DataBase which contains tables( class Table) and I must overload operators to get next result:
dataBase(3,5)=someTable;  - this code must replace tables 3-5 from database with table someTable.

So, help me please whith  overload methods signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for overloading the function call operator within your `DataBase` class is:

```
reference_type operator()( int first, int last );
```

Where `reference_type` is a proxy reference, that is a helper type that stores a reference to the database and the first and last indexes, and overloads `operator=` to do the replacement. Something in the lines of:

```
class proxy_reference
{
public:
    proxy_reference( DataBase& database, int first, int last )
      : _database( database )
      , _first( first ), _last( last )
    {}

    --something-- operator=( Table const& someTable )
    {
        /* replace tables _first to _last from _database with someTable */
    }

private:
    DataBase& _database;
    int _first, _last;
};
```